# Jquery.min.js is conflict in socialengine4 framework?

Tags: jquery, socialengine

I am trying to use jquery.min.js in socialengine frame work.

it works fine but it affect the admin panel **Layout Editor**

I thing something conflict can any one help me to resolve it.

I am using loading the jquery.min.js in Activity module **Bootstrap.php** like bellow

> $headScript = new Zend_View_Helper_HeadScript();

$headScript->appendFile('application/modules/Activity/externals/scripts/core.js');

$headScript->appendFile('application/modules/Activity/externals/scripts/jquery.min.js');

> $headScript->appendFile('application/modules/Activity/externals/scripts/jquery.hovercard.min.js');

Comment: you can resolve the conflict using `var $j = $.noConflict()` code and then you should use `$j` instead of `$`.

Comment: @CodefOrmer: Thanx for your response it works fine. but it affect in     application\modules\Core\views\scripts\admin-content\index.tpl . It shows error in firebug like:activator.getParent is not a function  
var element = activator.getParent('li');

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by including:

```
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

in your code and assinging all your "$." with "jQuery."